# How to detect if the browser support flash?

Tags: flash, detect

I just have two version of my site

one is design for Flash supported (like Desktop) and the other one is for Mobile devices

I just want to know if I can detect and if is true (support) they will stay the same website assuming is `http://mywebsite.com` but the link will display `http://mywebsite.com/?flash=true` and if is not support I will redirect them to `http://mywebsite.com/?flash=false`

sorry for the dumb question you don't have to give me an answer but if you can provide me some sort of resource where can I dig the information and study about it myself

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This javascript code fragment will do the job:

```
var _flash_installed = ((typeof navigator.plugins !== "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] === "object") || (window.ActiveXObject && (new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) !== false));
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html

May help you.

However you shouldn't rely on Flash beeing also enabled even if installed. I, for example, don't let Flash start automatically, but enable it manually.