# send javascript variable to server in the absence of flash

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash

Note: This question is not about detection of flash in the browser.

see this http://hasseg.org/stuff/fontList/example.html

I want to send  font list to server(php page) through javascript xml http request.

Font list generates only in the presence of flash in the browser. if flash is absent, font list will not generate.

I am able to successfully send font list to server in the presence of flash. But if flash is not present I am not able  to send some text like "noflash" instead of fonts.

Now I want to send a text "noflash" to server if flash is not present.

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendfont(s){
s = s.toString(" ");
send  = "fontlist="+encodeURIComponent(s);

ajax("logic.php",send);
}

function ajax(url, send){
var ar = null;
try{
    ar=new XMLHttpRequest();
}catch(e){
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        var ax=    ['Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0','Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0','Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0','Msxml2.XMLHTTP','Microsoft.XMLHTTP'],i=ax.length;
        while(--i){
            try{
                ar=new ActiveXObject(ax[i]);
                break;
            }catch(e){
            }
        }
    }
    if(ar==null){
        alert("Update your browser.");
    }
}
ar.open("POST",url,true);
ar.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ar.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(ar.readyState==4){
        if(ar.status==200||ar.status==304){
            document.body.innerHTML=ar.responseText.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
        };
    }
}
ar.send(send);
};

function populateFontList(fontArr)
{
var i = 0, xf = [];
for (var key in fontArr)
{
    var f = fontArr[key];

    // trim
    f = f.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');

    if (f.match(/[_\-\s]Italic$/)
        || f.match(/[_\-\s](Demi)?[Bb]old$/)
        || f.match(/[_\-\s]Medium$/)
        || f.match(/[_\-\s](Ultra)?[Ll]ight$/)
        || f.match(/[_\-\s]Condensed$/)
        || f.replace(/\s*Regular$/, '')
        )xf[i++] = f;

}

    sendfont(xf);

}
</script>

<object id="fontListSWF" name="fontListSWF" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"    data="FontList.swf" width="1" height="1"><param name="movie" value="FontList.swf">
<embed src="FontList.swf" width="1" height="1"></embed>
</object>
```

I want to replace 'xf' variable with "noflash  and sent it to server if flash is absent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if the browser support flash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576999/how-to-detect-if-the-browser-support-flash)

Comment: @Diodeus  I know how to detect flash. But this is not my problem. Please read the question. also remove the duplicate tag.

Comment: Where in your code you are detecting if flash is present? I mean, you know how to do and you need to do, so...

Comment: @Hisamu Yes. It is too long so I didnt included in the code. but assume that i have included. here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvee/VQ98p/